# Disable HTTP OPTIONS verb in IIS 7

Tags: iis, request-filtering

My .NET 4.0 webapp is running on Windows Server 2008 on IIS 7.5 using an Integrated pipeline.

I want to only enable the "big four" HTTP verbs. According to [the documentation](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/verbs), this should do the trick:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <verbs allowUnlisted="false" applyToWebDAV="true">
        <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
        <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
        <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
        <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />                    
      </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But, as you might have already guessed, it does not. Doing an `OPTION` request still results in "HTTP 200 OK", as do `LOCK`, `PROPFIND` and some others. All of this with WebDAV *not* being installed.

Removing the `<add verb="GET" ...` line results in IIS correctly responding with a HTTP 404.6 (Verb Denied) error.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Maybe try using IIS Manager to create and modify that file in case there's a problem with the file itself.

Comment: @Andrew Yep, already tried that. IIS reports no errors in Web.config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aaand I was woefully wrong. IIS was indeed responding with 404, but an `<httpErrors>` section kicked in and served up my "404.html" page with HTTP 200 status.